# JSTL violating Encapsulation

Tags: jstl, encapsulation

JSTL tags in .jsp can violate encapsulation just like that:

```
< jsp:getProperty property="aPrivateID" name="someObj" />
```

gets the value of the variable "aPrivateID" declared as "private" in "someObj".

Isn't this a bit odd?

Is/n't there a way to control it and stop JSTL having access 
to private members of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example JSP doesn't get the value of the private variable `aPrivateID`.   Instead that JSP calls a **public** accessor method named `getAPrivateID()` and returns the result. Encapsulation is preserved.

Comment: Thx-- haven't checked but this answers.